# how to add a sound to link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, audio

HI all,

I want to add a sound to my link please tell me is there any jquery or javascript to add sound
i have used following but its not working..

```
<div align="center"><a href="our_product.html" class="footermenu" onmouseover="MM_controlSound('play','document.CS1276334226609','drop/downloadb12bb644.mp3')">Our Product I</a></div>
```

Thanks
Mayur

Comment: do you want play music on click or a ding dong like sound to notify a click...

Comment: No i want to play a sound on mousehover link

Comment: i have edit my answer you can find your answer on below link.

Comment: Please God, don't do it!

Answer (score 2):

You should go for very popular **[SoundManager](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/)** Javascript script and it works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jplayer](http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/) for that. You just have to hide the player ui.

**Edit:**
You can find plenty of demos (with code) here: http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/latest/demos.htm

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to play music [premium beat player](http://www.premiumbeat.com/)

**EDIT**

than you should use this [**play sound on click**](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/sound)
if you want to play sound on click link.